# In Bootstrap, two `span`s in the same "fluid" row aren't behaving similarly. Why?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, formatting, responsive-design

I'm trying to customize a "responsive" Bootstrap theme that is driven by LESS code, and I'm having some problems I can't solve. First, let me show you the code:

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span7">
        <div class="hero-unit">
            <h2 class="gw-tweak2">This is line 1.</h2>
            <h1 class="gw-tweak2">This is (big) line 2.</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gw-tweak3 span5">
        <img src="img/portrait-square-nobkgd-250sq.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the relevant LESS code:

```
.hero-unit {
    background-color: @backgd-color;

    h2.gw-tweak2 {
        color: lighten(@subhead-color, 6%);
        font-size: 22px;
    }
    h1.gw-tweak2 {
        color: darken(@subhead-color, 8%);
        font-size: 44px;
    }
}

div.row-fluid>div.gw-tweak3 {    // gw: applies to the span4 div 
                                 //   that contains the portrait img
    float: left;
}
```

I'm trying to prevent side effects that my changes might otherwise cause by narrowing my rule's selector with the classes "gw-tweak2" and "gw-tweak3". (FYI, "gw-" is there so I can find my changes quickly.)

The HTML code is describing a horizontal slice of my webpage. On the left is what Bootstrap calls a “hero-unit” (think of it as a formatted text box), and on the right is a 250x250-pixel photo.

For those of you who do not know what “responsive” means, it means that as the width of the webpage narrows, the various elements of the page resize and rearrange themselves so that the resulting page always looks good. (This way, the same webpage will look acceptable on a computer, a tablet, and a smart phone.)

Here's the desired effect I want (within the range of webpage sizes most appropriate to a desk computer): As the width of the webpage decreases, the height of the hero unit increases. As this is happening, the image moves down so that it is vertically centered with respect to the height of the hero unit.

Here's what actually happens: For a while, the image's vertical positioning remains unchanged. Then at some point, the image starts shrinking and at the same time starts drifting up toward the imaginary horizontal line that runs through the top boundary of the hero unit (i.e., the beginning of the area being defined by this code).

Here's an observation that seems to be closely related to the problem: When I use Firebug to highlight the area “covered” by a given HTML tag, I find that the height of the “span7” area (the hero unit) and the height of the “span5” area are different. (I assumed that Bootstrap would make them all the same height--after all, a “row-fluid” `div` seems to represent a rectangular slice of the webpage.) Also, as the webpage is narrowed, the area of the "span5" element shrinks to exactly cover the `img` as it shrinks.

Maybe nothing can be done; I've seen some webpages that say that centering an element vertically is just not something that HTML does. But even some insight on why Bootstrap is behaving the way I'm describing could help me modify the current behavior in a way that makes the result less godawful.

Comment: can you create a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: No, I personally don't know how to use jsfiddle to do that. Sorry I didn't make this clear, but the template uses LESS, which translates to over 500 lines of CSS. I want to make changes to the LESS file only. It doesn't look like jsfiddle can work from a LESS file.

Comment: Then [Codepen](http://codepen.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Their is no need of defining gw-tweak3 beacuse the structure is already set to float. Only have to do is make the image width 100%...

```
div.row-fluid > div.gw-tweak3 {   
    float: left; // Remove this
    img { 
      width:100%; margin:10px 0; vertical-align:middle;
    } // Add this
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. What I'm trying to do is to get the `img` to center itself vertically. Will your added code help do that? When I tried it, it didn't make a difference.

Comment: for vertically aligned the img to the div is done by using margin, add some margin to top and bottom, make height auto as it resize itself with the width keeping a exact ratio... check the about code...

Comment: I've just spent two hours trying to get Bootstrap + LESS to work on Codepen.io, with no success. I'll try what you suggested, but I won't have time to for a few days. Thanks.